# How to create deferenced copy of an object in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an entity which I use to bind data with my WPF UI. I am in need to create a copy of the entity which I can use as "original" data anytime.

Just creating new object and then assigning also carries references with it. So I need a copy of entity object which has no effect of changes made on its source.

My entity contains value type properties and several nested collections.

Any suggestions/ideas on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you do a deep copy an object in .Net (C# specifically)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)

Comment: Yes, it is kind of a dupe but all the answers here seem to use BinaryFomatter.

Comment: The term is "Deep Copy" and better state "without using serialization".

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own copy constructor:
This shows how.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116(v=vs.80).aspx

For collections you will need to copy the data too. Array.Copy will work for most for A hashtable you might need to go as far as Serialization or simply recreating the table.

```
SomeType[] myArray = new SomeType[orig.Count+ 1];

orig.CopyTo(myArray, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Deep Copy in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this project: https://github.com/havard/copyable